# Define an arbitrary number of datasources in external Spring Boot config

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot web service that serves different types of data, where each type resides in its own database. As new types are added, I don't want to have to configure the datasource for each type in the code. This is what I've got so far:

Data types and their database connections are defined in `application.yml`:

```yml
datatypes:
  someType:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://mydatabase.com:5432/some_type
    username: user1
    password: pass1
  otherType:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://mydatabase.com:5432/other_type
    username: user2
    password: pass2
```

A configuration class reads the properties and creates `DataSource`s and `JdbcTemplate`s:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class JdbcConfig {
  
  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datatypes")
  public Map<String, DataSourceProperties> databaseConfig() {
    return new HashMap<>();
  }

  @Bean
  public Map<String, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate> jdbcTemplateMap() {
    Map<String, DataSourceProperties> databaseConfig = databaseConfig();

    Map<String, DataSource> dataSourceMap = databaseConfig().entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> 
            entry.getValue().initializeDataSourceBuilder().build()));

    return dataSourceMap.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry ->
            new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(entry.getValue())));
  }
}
```

And finally a repository that fetches data based on its type:

```java
@Repository
public class MyRepository {
  @Autowired
  private Map<String, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate> jdbcTemplateMap;

  public Item getItem(String dataType, String id) {
    String sql = "select * from item where id = :id";
    return jdbcTemplateMap.get(dataType)
               .queryForObject(sql, Map.of("id", id), new ItemRowMapper());
  }
}
```

When Spring tries to autowire `jdbcTemplateMap` in the repository it can't find any jdbc template beans, so the auto configuration kicks in but fails as the properties for the datasource are not where it expects them in the yml. This can be fixed by disabling the auto configuration: `@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)`

This setup *almost* works. However, since the `DataSource` instances are not registered in the application context, I miss out on some other auto configuration magic, like the actuator health check for instance. I tried registering them myself, by adding this to `JdbcConfig` and calling `registerDataSource()` from the `jdbcTemplateMap()` bean method:

```java
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

private void registerDataSource(String beanName, DataSource dataSource) {
  ConfigurableApplicationContext context = 
      (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext;
  ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = context.getBeanFactory();
  beanFactory.registerSingleton(beanName, dataSource);
}
```

With this in place I should be able to enable the datasouce auto configuration again, but it runs before `jdbcTemplateMap()` has a chance to run. Actuator won't pick them up either. Can this be fixed?