# Using ByteBuddy to generate Spring Boot configuration

Tags: java, spring-boot, byte-buddy

I'm trying to generate Spring Boot configuration code in order to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67720388/define-an-arbitrary-number-of-datasources-in-external-spring-boot-config). This is what I've got so far:

```java
//@Configuration <- trying to add this through BB
public class GeneratedConfigBase {
  @Bean
  public Object hello() {
    System.out.println("hello");
    return new Object();
  }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    generateConf();
    SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
  }

  private static void generateConf() {
    new ByteBuddy()
        .subclass(GeneratedConfigBase.class)
        .name("com.example.GeneratedConfig")
        .annotateType(AnnotationDescription.Builder.ofType(Configuration.class).build())
        .make()
        .load(TestApp.class.getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.UsingLookup.of(
            MethodHandles.privateLookupIn(GeneratedConfigBase.class, MethodHandles.lookup()
        ));
  }
}
```

The above won't print "hello" when running the app. I'm not at all sure about the `load()` part, but Spring Boot may not pick up the configuration for any number of reasons. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring scans the class path by iterating over class files. Your generated class will not be visible via these scans, it does not have a class file representation.

To make your class visible, you'd need to register it explicitly. I thibk Spring offers a builder for this purpose where you currently run a single main class.

Comment: Managed to get it working by adding `.getLoaded()` to the ByteBuddy chain, returning the `Class` from `generateConf` and adding it to the run sources: `SpringApplication.run(new Class[] {generatedClass, TestApp.class}, args);`

Comment: Thankyou, very helpful to highlight the workaround to this limitation. I've managed to clone some `@AutoConfiguration` classes, amending their annotations to support new properties.